# Attempting to transfer my android app to gradle, having some issues with building

Tags: android, intellij-idea, gradle

I'm attempting to transfer my app, Rymate Notes, from an imported IntelliJ project in Android Studio to a proper full blown gradle project. In order to make sure the new project folder is reasonably clean, I've decided to do it manually by copyin the source files and resources into a new folder.

Everything was going well until I decided to try and compile, and it doesn't compile.

The error I'm getting is https://gist.github.com/rymate1234/7896787

I have no idea what is causing this error, so any help is appreciated.

UPDATE - I have no idea https://gist.github.com/rymate1234/7896787#file-output2-log

Comment: Urk. That's one cryptic error message. If you can create a project that reproduces it, I'd consider filing a tools bug over on http://b.android.com -- even if there is a problem with your configuration, the error message should be less obtuse.

Comment: Please add the contents of build files and error messages to your question instead of linking them. Postings here should be self-contained.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're hitting bug https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=42752 where the AAPT tool (which is what does resource packaging in the Android build) crashes on certain types of errors. The culprit I've heard of is comment #5 in that bug, where a menu.xml file references a nonexistent string.